# Why server goes into infinite loop when same client communicates with server again?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, epoll

I implemented server code using EPOLL in c++. 
Server runs for infinite time for accepting new events.This server accepting both type of TCP and UDP packets. This works fine for UDP type. But when run for TCP packets, it accepts all incoming events from client for the first time but when client finishes his all task first time and again same client wanted to do same stuffs on the same server it stuck into infinite loop.
Please look into the given code and point out the flaw.

Server Code :

```
    //Function which waiting for epoll events and process these events
int epoll_ready(int efd, string ListenIP) {
struct epoll_event event[MAX_EVENTS];
struct info *dat;
int i, rfd;
cout<<endl;
printf("           Waiting for epoll event.\n");
rfd = epoll_wait(efd, event, MAX_EVENTS, -1);

cout << "   No. of ready file descriptor for requested I/O : " << rfd << endl;
if (rfd == -1)
    return -1;

for (i = 0; i < rfd; i++) {
    dat = (struct info *) event[i].data.ptr;
    cout<<"\n******************************************************************************"<<endl;
    cout << "prototype-- " << dat->prototyp << " FD-- " << dat->fd << " Connection type--  " << dat->contyp ;
    cout<<" Port no-- "<<dat->srcport<<endl;
    if ((event[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (event[i].events & EPOLLHUP) || (!(event[i].events & EPOLLIN)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Epoll Error Occured FD= %d\n", dat->fd);
        close(dat->fd);
    } 
    //Accepting TCP connection
    else if ((dat->prototyp == 'T')  && (dat->contyp == 'S'))
    {
        struct sockaddr in_addr;
        socklen_t in_len;
        int infd;

        in_len = sizeof in_addr;
        infd = accept(dat->fd, &in_addr, &in_len);

        if (infd == -1) {
            if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                printf("Accepting all incoming connection\n");   
            } else {
                perror("Error in accepting");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Connection accepted from TCP client at port no. %d \n",dat->srcport);

        }
        int s;
        /* Make the accepted sock fd non-blocking and add it to the list of efd to monitor. */
        s = make_socket_non_blocking(infd);
        if (s == -1) {
            printf("Error in make socket non_blocking\n");
        }
        do_randport_accept(efd, dat->srcport, infd, ListenIP);

        s = make_socket_non_blocking(dat->fd);
        if (s == -1)
        {
            printf("Error in make socket non_blocking\n");
        }
        cout<<"******************************************************************************"<<endl;
        continue;
    }
    //Code for receiving and sending data to TCP clients
    else if((event[i].events & EPOLLIN) && (dat->prototyp == 'T')    )//Code for receiving and sending data to TCP clients
    { 
       cout<<"Enter into receive function...."<<endl;
        int bytecount = 0, bytecoun = 0, flag = 0;
        char buffer[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
        bytecount = recv(dat->fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if( bytecount < 0)
        {    if(errno == EAGAIN){
                printf("Read later\n");
                continue;
             }
             if (errno == ECONNRESET){
                 printf("Connection closed by client\n");
             } 
             if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK){//no more data to receive
                 int s=0;
                 if ((s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, dat->fd, &event[i]) < 0)) {
                   perror("Error in epoll_ctl_DEL\n");
                 }
                 close(dat->fd);
                 continue;
             }
             else{
                printf("Error receiving data = %d errmesg = %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));

                continue;
             }
        }
        if(bytecount == 0)
        {  int s = 0;
 //               struct epoll_event event; //ADDED CODE may or may not   be required
 //               event.data.ptr = (struct info *) dat;
 //               event.events = EPOLLIN;
           if ((s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, dat->fd, &event[i]) < 0)) {
                perror("Error in epoll_ctl_DEL\n");
           }
           cout<<"Client close the connection.."<<endl;
           close(dat->fd);
          continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Received bytes from TCP client : %d\nRequest received from TCP client : \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer+2);
 //                int num = ( (unsigned char)buffer[0] << 8 | (unsigned char)buffer[1] );
 //                 cout<<"Packet Length-- "<<num<<endl;
        }

         if ((bytecoun = send(dat->fd, buffer, bytecount, 0)) == -1) {
            if (errno == ECONNRESET)
               close(dat->fd); 
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data to TCP client %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
        else
            printf("Echo Sent bytes : %d\nEcho message send to TCP client : \"%s\"\n", bytecoun, buffer+2); 

 //            event[i].data.ptr = dat;
 //            event[i].events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET;    
 //            epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, dat->fd, &event[i]);

        make_socket_non_blocking(dat->fd);
       cout<<"******************************************************************************"<<endl;
     continue;
    }//End Code for receiving and sending data to TCP clients

//       else if(event[i].events & EPOLLOUT)
//        { cout<<"Enter into send function.."<<endl;
//            int bytecoun = 0;
//            char buffer[1024];
//            if ((bytecoun = send(dat->fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) == -1) {
//                if (errno == ECONNRESET)
//                   close(dat->fd); 
//                fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data to TCP client %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
//            }
//            else
//                printf("Echo Sent bytes : %d\nEcho message send to TCP client : \"%s\"\n", bytecoun, buffer); 
//              make_socket_non_blocking(dat->fd);
//             close(dat->fd);
//          continue;
//        }
//        
    //code for receiving message from UDP client and sending echo message back to client 
    else if ((dat->prototyp == 'U') && (dat->contyp) == 'S' ) {
        cout<<"Enter into UDP function..."<<endl; 
        struct sockaddr_in src = {0};
        char buf[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
        int nByt1 = sizeof(buf);
        int i = sizeof(src), ret = 0;
        ret = (recvfrom(dat->fd, (char*) buf, nByt1, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &src, (socklen_t*) & i));
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("Recvfrom failed\n");
        }
        cout<<"Received byte : "<<strlen(buf)<<endl;
        cout << "Data packet receive from UDP client : " << "\"" << buf << "\" " << endl;
        if (strcmp(buf, "exit") == 0) {
            cout << "Exit from receiving data..." << endl;
            break;
        }
        int tem = 0;
        int nByt = strlen(buf);
        int addr_siz = sizeof (src);
        if (tem = (sendto(dat->fd, buf, nByt, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &src, addr_siz)) != 1) {
            printf("ECHO bytes [%d] and message sent successfully to client : \"%s\"\n", strlen(buf), buf);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in sending to client %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
        memset(buf, NULL, BUFF_SIZE);


        make_socket_non_blocking(dat->fd);
       cout<<"******************************************************************************"<<endl;
      continue;
    }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

function code for-- void do_randport_accept();

```
   vector <struct info> randport_list;
   int k = 0;
   //Function for make creating and adding into epoll of connection accepted FDs
   void do_randport_accept(int efd, int randPort, int randfd, string ListenIP) {

if (randPort) {
    randport_list.push_back(info());
    randport_list[k].fd = randfd;
    randport_list[k].srcport = randPort;
    strcpy(randport_list[k].srcip, ListenIP.c_str());
    randport_list[k].destport = 0;
    randport_list[k].destip = NULL;
    randport_list[k].prototyp = 'T';
    randport_list[k].contyp = 'R';
}
int s = 0;
struct epoll_event event[MAX_EVENTS] = {0};
event[k].data.ptr = (void *) &randport_list[k];
event[k].events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLHUP;

if ((s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, randport_list[k].fd, &event[k]) < 0)) {
    perror("Error in epoll_ctl_add_random_port\n");
} else {
    printf("Accepted Fds Added into EPOLL_CTL successfully....\n");
}
k++;
 }
```

Any other insights to where I go wrong are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this code handle all error ?

Comment: If you close an accepted socket you also need to remove it from the poll set.

Comment: I do, but problem still exist.